# Using HashMaps in creating a game of 15 puzzle?

Tags: java

I am creating a simple game of 15 puzzle (Please see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle). I have an array of 4 by 4 buttons and want to know the best way to handle a user clicking on a button and moving around the numbers.

I have started off by creating a JavaFX gridpane to display the buttons as well as a HashMap (suggested by multiple people) to store a mapping between the displayed number (1-15) and the button at that location.

I populate the map with class objects "Btn"

```
public class Btn {
    private int ID;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Button button;
```

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {

                Btn btn = new Btn(count, j, i, new Button("" + count));
                map.put(count, btn);
                btn.button.setMinSize(100, 100);
                btn.button.setOnAction(e -> {
                    if (isMoveLegal(btn) == true) {
                        move(btn);
                    }
                });
                count++;

                grid.add(btn.button, j, i);
            }
        }
```

So far it has worked quite well. In the isMoveLegal() method I check if the empty field is above, left, right, or below the clicked button. Which gets quite complicated because of the HashMaps nature of not preserving any order. But my real problem lies in the move() method. Since there is no order, I can't just switch 2 map nodes or can I?

```
if (MoveDir.equals("Right")) {
   map.get((btn.getYs()+1)*4 - (4-btn.getXs())).button.setText("" + map.get(btn.getID()).getID());
   map.get(btn.getID()).button.setText("" + map.get((btn.getYs()+1)*4 - (4-btn.getXs())).getID());

   int tempID = map.get(btn.getID()).getID();
   map.get(btn.getID()).setID(16);
   map.get((btn.getYs()+1)*4 - (4-btn.getXs())).setID(tempID);
//   System.out.println(map.get(btn.getID()).getID());
//   System.out.println(map.get((btn.getYs()+1)* 4 - (4-btn.getXs())).getID());

   map.get(btn.getID()).setYs(map.get(btn.getID()).getYs()+1);
   map.get((btn.getYs()+1)* 4 - (4-btn.getXs())).setYs(map.get((btn.getYs()+1)* 4 - (4-btn.getXs())).getYs()-1);
```

This is what I have come up with so far, which extremely complicated and tedious. To quickly sum it up, I first switch the labels of the buttons, then I change the ID variables of the 2 buttons, and then I change the cord variables (x & y) to indicate their new location in map/grid. 
I'm pretty sure I have gone way too far with this and there is a simpler solution to all of this but I am just unsure what that would be. Should I ditch the HashMap entirely and just use an object array of Btns?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but this question isn't quite making sense to me. Please explain the game, please explain the purpose of the HashMap, explain *why* "people" are recommending that you use this, and who these "people" are.

Comment: The game the OP is referring to is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle . I believe the question is how to map a UI of 4x4 buttons arranged in a grid to the logic of deciding whether a move can be made and making that move. The OP is currently using a HashMap to hold a mapping between the button id (a number 1-15) and the button itself. I don't have permission to edit the question, and can't answer as it's on hold. :)

Comment: To provide a cut-down answer, I believe you need to abstract the buttons from the underlying game data. the buttons can contain their (x,y) location and there can be a separate 2D array that stores the location of each number. When you click a button, use the location to look up which number is in the array and then figure out whether you can move and update the number each button displays.

Comment: Yes sorry not the best at formulating clear & concise questions. So yes as @Caleb has mentioned it is the game of 15 puzzle that I am trying to create. And my problem is indeed the logic of communicating between my UI and the code wether a move is possible and then to execute the move. As to who suggested I use a HashMap, it was an Computer Science Masters student who is a family friend, although my Computer Science professor also hinted that I use HashMaps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that your UI and your data structure are too tightly coupled. You need to separate them, give them their own responsibilities, and use communication (method calls) between them to make things happen.

For example, the UI should only be responsible for displaying the numbers and allowing the user to click a number to perform a move. Using a gridpane of buttons seems reasonable for this. Each button only needs to know it's x,y coordinate.

The data model should be a 2-dimensional array that contains the number at that location. For example:

```
+-+-+-+
|4|1|8|
+-+-+-+
|2|3|7|
+-+-+-+
| |5|6|
+-+-+-+
```

(You can figure out how to represent the empty space. Maybe a null, or the number '0' or '-1')

The data model can be wrapped in a data object that handles questions about and manipulations to the data model. For example, one method it might contain is `getTheNumberAtLocation(x,y)` which the buttons will call, and will return the number at that location. The buttons will use this to determine what number they should show.

Another method it might contain is `isThereASpaceNextToLocation(x,y)`. This would return whether or not a space exists next to the location given by the x,y. The button will call this method to determine whether or not it can be clicked.

Finally, you could have a `moveLocationToEmptySpace(x,y)` which will manipulate the data to put the number at the current location into the empty space. After that, all the buttons should call `getTheNumberAtLocation(x,y)` to update the number they are showing.

By arranging your code like this you've nicely separated the concern of the UI (show text, handle button clicks) from the concern of maintaining the game state (checking if a move is valid, performing a move, determining the state of the board). Now when you write code it will be easier to write because each method will be responsible for a small, manageable piece of logic.

To summarise:

```
Gridpane (4x4)
  -> Button
      -> label [calls GameData.getTheNumberAtLocation]
      -> click [calls GameData.isThereASpaceNextToLocation, moveLocationToEmptySpace]

GameData
  -> Array (4x4) (private)
      -> Integer (1-15)
  -> getTheNumberAtLocation(x,y)
  -> isThereASpaceNextToLocation(x,y)
  -> moveLocationToEmptySpace(x,y)
```